ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED при запуске selenoid
Учу selenium и столкнулся с проблемой у меня в докере запущен OpenCart и так же на Wsl запущен selenoid(докер контейнеры так же отображаются) я пытаюсь запустить свои тесты и получаю ошибку  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
если просто запускаю тесты без selenoid то они прекрасно отрабатывают
ниже предоставлю код conftest
import datetime
import logging
import os
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", default="chrome")
    parser.addoption("--url", default="http://localhost/")
    # parser.addoption("--headless", action="store_true")
    # parser.addoption("--noheadless", action="store_false", dest="headless")
    parser.addoption("--log_level", action="store", default="INFO")
    parser.addoption("--executor", action="store", default="127.0.0.1")


@pytest.fixture
def url(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--url")


@pytest.fixture
def browser(request, url):
    browser_name = request.config.getoption('--browser')
    # log_level = request.config.getoption("--log_level")
    executor = request.config.getoption("--executor")
    # logger = logging.getLogger(request.node.name)
    # logs_dir = "logs"
    # if not os.path.exists(logs_dir):
    #     os.makedirs(logs_dir)
    # file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f"logs/{request.node.name}.log")
    # file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
    # logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    # logger.setLevel(level=log_level)
    #
    # logger.info("===> Test %s started at %s" % (request.node.name, datetime.datetime.now()))
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        options = ChromeOptions()
    elif browser_name == "edge":
        options = EdgeOptions()
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        options = Options()

    capabilities = {
        "browserName": browser_name
    }
    for c, l in capabilities.items():
        options.set_capability(c, l)

    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=f"http://{executor}:4444/wd/hub",
        options=options

    )
    # driver.log_level = log_level
    # driver.logger = logger
    driver.test_name = request.node.name

    # logger.info("Browser %s launched" % browser_name)

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)

    def fin():
        driver.quit()
        # logger.info("===> Test %s finished at %s" % (request.node.name, datetime.datetime.now()))

    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return driver


